# Running a 32bit executable

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

i am trying to run a 32bit executable on my 64bit oneric. Here a short overview of the situation. But i have to prepend ia32 libs are installed:

```
> aptitude search ia32
i   ia32-libs - ia32 shared libraries for use on amd64 and ia64 syste
```

First of all i tested the filetype:

```
> file tipp10
tipp10: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
```

I am using 64bit oneric, with the not so recent kernel, because i didn't restart yet.

```
> uname -a
Linux christchurch 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As i said normal execution doesn't work. It aborts with file or directory not found.

```
> strace ./tipp10
execve("./tipp10", ["./tipp10"], [/* 46 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
[...]
```

Here the ldd output on my system. On my 64bit Debian Server the programm is reconized as a dynamic linked programm and a few lib references are outputed. But on my ubuntu:

```
> ldd tipp10
    \tdas Programm ist nicht dynamisch gelinkt
# german for: "The programm is not linked dynamic"
```

Can anyone help me please. I don't unterstand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

This helps me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 lsb-core
```

Source:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/852101?comments=all